# Design Automation API - Token Refresh

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Am trying to access forge api endpoint using 2- legged authentication token, but at certain point of time my token becomes invalid or expired. Is that any option to refresh/ increase token expire time in 2- legged authentication process?

Answer (score 2):

For 2-legged token, once they expire, you have no choice but to request another one.  That being said, I think this will be managed for you if you use one of the forge/design-automation sdk.